# Populate ListView with SQLite

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I am creating an app where you can insert tasks to do and amend them. I currently can view the tasks in a list which I have created, however when I click on the list only the title is shown, although the other entries aren't shown.

Within the entry screen I have code which populates the Entry screen with previous information:

```
mSaveButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.diaryform_ib_save);
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Title: "+ mTitle);
    Intent showTitle = getIntent();
    String fieldTitle = showTitle.getStringExtra(Constants.DIARY_TITLE);
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Title 2: "+ fieldTitle);
    mTitle.setText(fieldTitle);

    Intent showEntry = getIntent();
    String fieldEntry = showEntry.getStringExtra(Constants.DIARY_ENTRY);
    mEntry.setText(fieldTitle);
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Entry: "+ mEntry);
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Entry 2: "+ fieldEntry);
```

I have Log messages in there so I can see what information is being given. For fieldTitle the title is passed and for fieldEntry null is passed. When I make both fieldTitle both fields are filled with the title.

Within my ListActivity class I have the following code snippet:

```
diaryDAO = new DAO(this); //Creates an instance of the DAO
    Cursor diaryCursor = diaryDAO.queryDiary(Diary.DiaryItem.LIST_PROJECTION, null, null); 
    Log.i(TAG, "I get to here!");
    String[] diaryDataColumns = { Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TITLE,Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_ENTRY }; 
    Log.i(TAG, "Also here");
    int[] viewIDs ={ R.id.textView1 }; 
    Log.i(TAG, "Diary Data Col" +diaryDataColumns);
    Log.i(TAG, "I'm here");

    //Creates backing adapter for the ListView
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") s
    SimpleCursorAdapter diaryAdapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(
              this,                            
              R.layout.activity_diary_list,     
              diaryCursor,                     
              diaryDataColumns,                     
              viewIDs                       
      );
    Log.i(TAG, "Now im here");

    this.setListAdapter(diaryAdapter);
```

Where I create the diaryDataColumns string I tried added the Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_ENTRY and it doesn't show within the entry screen BUT when I change the Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TITLE to ENTRY the list view and the entry shows the entry given.

Any ideas? Slightly confused as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

edit:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent openItem = new Intent(this, DiaryEntryActivity.class); 
    Cursor listCursor = (Cursor)l.getAdapter().getItem(position); 
    openItem.putExtra(Constants.DIARY_TITLE, listCursor.getString(1)); 
    startActivity(openItem); //Starts the intent actions
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call getIntent several times, how are you putting the data as an extra into the intent, from the other activity, show us the code

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you give two columns, but only one text view. The first given columns data will be populated in the text view, but I think, there is no data in the first column, but your second column contains data, and when you switch them, that data will be populated in the text view. Try it out with two textViews.
But I think to work with content provider is an effecient way, there is a good tutorial on vogella.com about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQLite, I suggest you look at using `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Typically, you subclass this class from the Android API and then use it to implement a `ContentProvider`. The `ContentProvider` subclass in turn delivers `Cursor`s to your app which can be used by a `CursorAdapter`. I suggest you start with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and then customize it from there.   You should also learn about `CursorLoader`s which allow you to load data from a database on a separate thread. For more details look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html.